# Cannot resolves symbol X, when defining multiple implicit vals

Tags: string, scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am testing out some code shown below that basically defines multiple implicit `val`s taking a string as input and converting it to corresponding types.

The problem I have is that the conversions like `toLong`, `toDouble` and `toInt` become unresolved for some reason.

```
class Parse[T](val f: String => T) extends (String => T) {
  def apply(s: String): T = f(s)
}

object Parse {
  def apply[T](f: String => T) = new Parse[T](f)

  implicit val parseLong: Parse[Long] = Parse[Long](s => s.toLong)
  implicit val parseDouble: Parse[Double] = Parse[Double](s => s.toDouble)
  implicit val parseInt: Parse[Int] = Parse[Int](s => s.toInt)
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that, since `Parse` extends `String => T`, implicits `parseLong`, `parseDouble`, `parseInt` define not only instances of `Parse` but also implicit conversions `String => Long`, `String => Double`, `String => Int`. And since `.toLong`, `.toDouble`, `.toInt` are extension methods, this creates ambiguities.

You can either remove `extends (String => T)` or resolve extension methods manually:

```
object Parse {
  def apply[T](f: String => T) = new Parse[T](f)

  implicit val parseLong: Parse[Long] = Parse[Long](s => new StringOps(s).toLong)
  implicit val parseDouble: Parse[Double] = Parse[Double](s => new StringOps(s).toDouble)
  implicit val parseInt: Parse[Int] = Parse[Int](s => new StringOps(s).toInt)
}
```